# How to get JSON data from the API key when the owner has given you the public and private key as well?

Tags: android, api, private, private-key

I was practicing on API's but when I asked my senior to assign me a different task he gave me a PRIVATE KEY, PUBLIC KEY, SECURITY KEY, and a link! 
Actually my senior is also stuck on that so he asked me to search solution for this. 
Now I don't know where I have to start, simple parse I can but I've never used or even seen private, public, security type API. 
please answer the followings :
1) why we encrypt in the form of private-public
2) how to get data from private-public security type API key in android studio
thanks in advance !!
I could not try because even I don't know where to get started !!! below I have shown simple parsing

```
package com.example.apitest1;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;        
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;        
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;        
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {      
private static final String URL_link="https://www.api.simplifiedcoding.in/course-apis/recyclerview/movies";
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
private List<dataModel> listitems;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
listitems=new ArrayList<>();
loadRecyclerViewData();
adapter=new dataAdapter(listitems,this);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);}
private void loadRecyclerViewData() {
final ProgressDialog progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(this);
progressDialog.setMessage("loading data");
progressDialog.show();
StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_link,
new Response.Listener<String>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {
progressDialog.dismiss();
try {
JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("movies");
for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
{
JSONObject object=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
dataModel list=new dataModel(object.getString("title"),                                                object.getString("language"));
listitems.add(list);                                    }
adapter=new dataAdapter(listitems,getApplicationContext());
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
catch (JSONException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
}});
RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For authentication, IMHO, you should override getHeaders , please try the following:

```
@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
       Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();                
       String credentials = "username:password";
       String auth = "Basic "+ Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
       headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
       headers.put("Authorization", auth);
       headers.put("consumer_key", oauth_consumer_key);
       headers.put("consumer_secret", oauth_consumer_secret);
       return headers;
}
```